# All Charts libraries for android does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm using latest version of android studio i tried to follow all steps required for adding Charts in my project from different Libraries([AnyChart](https://www.anychart.com/), [MpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), [Gruzer](https://github.com/Gruzer/simple-gauge-android)) but none of them work i ended up with red lines erros

so how can i solve this?

**Here is my gradel file**

```
  buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Here is my gradle app file dependencies**

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.Gruzer:simple-gauge-android:0.3.1'
implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

}

**Here is my main activity file,i get same problem to all Libraries.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ4bJ.png)

Comment: post full layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this work for me

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    }
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

if not worked... check your internet connection and try another dependencies like retrofit to make sure your gradle sync work as well